# Backup script I've been using with no issues for a while tossing an error on new database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been using the code below to drop and create a new backup named (current year database)_daily at midnight to allow my team to test new scripts or updates to our student information system.

It worked all last year, and this year for reasons I can't figure out, the script is tossing an error.

Here is the script:

```
USE master;
GO
-- the original database (use 'SET @DB = NULL' to disable backup)
DECLARE @SourceDatabaseName varchar(200)
DECLARE @SourceDatabaseLogicalName varchar(200)
DECLARE @SourceDatabaseLogicalNameForLog varchar(200)
DECLARE @query varchar(2000)
DECLARE @DataFile varchar(2000)
DECLARE @LogFile varchar(2000)
DECLARE @BackupFile varchar(2000)
DECLARE @TargetDatabaseName varchar(200)
DECLARE @TargetDatbaseFolder varchar(2000)

-- ****************************************************************

SET @SourceDatabaseName = '[DST18000RD]'                 -- Name of the source database
SET @SourceDatabaseLogicalName = 'DST18000RD'                -- Logical name of the DB ( check DB properties / Files tab )
SET @SourceDatabaseLogicalNameForLog = 'DST18000RD_log'  -- Logical name of the DB ( check DB properties / Files tab )
SET @BackupFile = 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\backup.dat'                                  -- FileName of the backup file
SET @TargetDatabaseName = 'DST18000RD_Daily'                        -- Name of the target database
SET @TargetDatbaseFolder = 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\'

-- ****************************************************************

SET @DataFile = @TargetDatbaseFolder + @TargetDatabaseName + '.mdf';
SET @LogFile = @TargetDatbaseFolder + @TargetDatabaseName + '.ldf';


-- Disconnect any users using @TargetDatabaseName
USE [master];

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';  
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), session_id) + ';'  
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id  = db_id('DST18000RD_Daily')

EXEC(@kill);

-- Backup the @SourceDatabase to @BackupFile location
IF @SourceDatabaseName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @query = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @SourceDatabaseName + ' TO DISK = ' + QUOTENAME(@BackupFile,'''')
PRINT 'Executing query : ' + @query;
EXEC (@query)
END
PRINT 'OK!';

-- Drop @TargetDatabaseName if exists
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE name = @TargetDatabaseName)
BEGIN
SET @query = 'DROP DATABASE ' + @TargetDatabaseName
PRINT 'Executing query : ' + @query;
EXEC (@query)
END
PRINT 'OK!'

-- Restore database from @BackupFile into @DataFile and @LogFile
SET @query = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @TargetDatabaseName + ' FROM DISK = ' + QUOTENAME(@BackupFile,'''') 
SET @query = @query + ' WITH MOVE ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceDatabaseLogicalName,'''') + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(@DataFile ,'''')
SET @query = @query + ' , MOVE ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceDatabaseLogicalNameForLog,'''') + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(@LogFile,'''')
PRINT 'Executing query : ' + @query
EXEC (@query)
PRINT 'OK!'
```

The script is not mine, I put together two scripts to get me what I needed.  Our old database DST17000RD, this script still works flawlessly.  On the new database DST18000RD, I get this error:

```
Executing query : BACKUP DATABASE [DST18000RD] TO DISK = 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\backup.dat'
Processed 1209552 pages for database 'DST18000RD', file 'DST18000RD' on file 23.
Processed 2 pages for database 'DST18000RD', file 'DST18000RD_log' on file 23.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 1209554 pages in 139.942 seconds (67.525 MB/sec).
OK!
OK!
Executing query : RESTORE DATABASE DST18000RD_Daily FROM DISK = 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\backup.dat' WITH MOVE 'DST18000RD' TO 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\DST18000RD_Daily.mdf' , MOVE 'DST18000RD_log' TO 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\DST18000RD_Daily.ldf'
Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Logical file 'DST18000RD' is not part of database 'DST18000RD_Daily'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
OK!
```

Some things to note that may just be me barking up the wrong tree.  DST17000RD database is compatibility level SQL Server 2012 (110) and the DST18000RD database is SQL Server 2017 (140).  The server was upgraded and migrated a couple months ago before the new database was created.

Any help is appreciated.  From what I can tell, I feel like the script is not renaming the MDF and LDF files before it tries to copy them for the *_daily database?  Honestly I'm not sure.  I'm a pretend DBA, self taught on an as needed basis.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You do not initialize the backup file and the backup file name itself has no clues about when it was created. So, are you accidentally adding to an existing backup file? Your logic is based on the assumption that there is only one backup and it would be safest to initialize the backup file using the with init option. David Browne has provided a query to see what is in the backup file. Try it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Thank you.  I will try it.   I'll also mark his answer correct if that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand what he was saying.  That was definitely the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you got the logical name of the db file wrong:

```
SET @SourceDatabaseLogicalName = 'DST18000RD'                -- Logical name of the DB ( check DB properties / Files tab )
```

and to run:

```
 RESTORE FILELIST ONLY FROM DISK = 'F:\Dev_Databases\Temp\backup.dat'
```

To see the correct logical file names.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're saying, but here is the logical and physical names of the database I'm trying to copy. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Z2uWLo1.png)

Comment: This was the issue, thank you.  I was appending to my old backup from last years database. :/ Dumb user issues strike again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to change the file logical name during the database restore, which is not possible even if you use the `MOVE` clause.

The `MOVE` clause allows you to change the location and the names of the physical files but does not do anything for the logical names.

**Fix**

You will have to use the existing logical names for your database, but once you have restored the database then use `ALTER DATABASE` command to change the logical names of your files using the following command:

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DST18000RD] 
  MODIFY FILE ( NAME = DST17000RD , NEWNAME = DST18000RD );
GO
```

Comment: If this were the case though then the script shouldn't work on any other database, correct?